# Is there a screenshot utility for Ubuntu with similar functionality to Shotty?

Tags: screenshot

**NB: See bottom for actual question**

---

There is an awesome screenshot utility for Windows called [Shotty](http://shotty.devs-on.net/en/Overview.aspx). It preserves translucency and drop shadow effects in screenshots. For example:

[image]

However, a screenshot from Ubuntu's built in utility does not preserve these effects, and looks pretty bad in comparison:

[image]

So, is there a screenshot utility for Ubuntu that will preserve the "eye-candy" like Shotty does?

Comment: Have you tried "shutter"?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Perhaps you should post that as an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with the way display servers and window compositors interact in Linux (as opposed to Windows where the two are coupled much more tightly). However you can post-process the image to add a drop shadow similar to that added by the window compositor.

### Find a suitable drop shadow filter

I found and played around a bit with [ImageMagick’s `-shadow` filter](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#shadow) and came close with these parameters:

```sh
convert :input.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x5+2+2 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage :output.png
```

As a bonus the shadow uses transparency for image formats like PNG (at 32 bit colour depth) that support it. Result from the example in your question:

[image: screenshot with drop shadow]

You can find a more in-depth explanation on the shadow filter in the [Examples of ImageMagick Usage](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow).

### Combine the filter with a screenshot tool

We can write a small script to combine the above filter with a screenshot tool like `gnome-screenshot`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
printf -v filename '%s/screenshot %(%F %T)T.png' "$HOME" -1
tmpfile="$(exec mktemp --tmpdir --suffix=.png screenshot.XXXXXXXXXX)"
trap 'rm -f -- "$tmpfile"' EXIT
gnome-screenshot "$@" -f "$tmpfile"
convert ":$tmpfile" \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x5+2+2 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage ":$filename"
```

### …or use what’s already there

It appears the GNOME developers had a similar idea and integrated a shadow filter into their screenshot tool:

```sh
gnome-screenshot --window --border-effect=shadow
```

This creates almost the same visual effect as above:

[image]

You can unbind the default keyboard shortcut for screenshots and create an identical shortcut for a custom command like the one above.

For more info see [`gnome-screenshot(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gnome-screenshot.1.html).